# How to solve generic type issue once we introduce one possible conformation to it in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am working on this custom function:

```
func customPrint<T: CustomStringConvertible>(_ value: T...) {
    var string: String = ""
    value.forEach { item in
        string += " " + String(describing: item)
    }
    print(string)
}
```

My issue is when I use one type and then use other type! for example this would work fine:

```
customPrint("hello", "100")
```

But this would not:

```
customPrint("hello", 100)
```

Xcode issue:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'

The error is understandable for me, but my goal is to be able use String or Int beside together for feeding my function.
So how can i let my generic works for all types that conform to generic? obviously String and Int conforming to CustomStringConvertible, but they cannot get used both together for my function, looking to solve this issue.

*Here what i am trying to solve:
I am thinking to use type `Any` like `Any...` where this Any type can conform to `CustomStringConvertible`.*

Comment: You mean `any` lowercased. Unfortunately this is only available with `Swift 5.7`.

Comment: No, Any like `Any`

Answer (score 2):

Since generics constraint the type of the arguments to be uniform, I would suggest doing something like below:

```
func customPrint(_ value: CustomStringConvertible...) {
    var string: String = ""
    value.forEach { item in
        string += " " + String(describing: item)
    }
    print(string)
}
```

Edit:

Thanks to [vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630618/vacawama), `Any` would also work with `String(describing:)`:

```
func customPrint(_ value: Any...) {     
    print(value.map({String(describing: $0)}).joined(separator: " ")) 
}
```

Comment: `Any` might be a better fit here than `CustomStringConvertible`, because `String(describing:)` works on things that aren't `CustomStringConvertible`.  Try `struct Foo { let I: Int = 5 }` and then `customPrint("Hello", Foo())`.  This better matches how `print()` itself works.

Comment: Shorter version that avoids leading space: `func customPrint(_ value: Any...) { print(value.map { String(describing: $0) }.joined(separator: " ")) }`

Comment: @vacawama: I can define a custom Struct which Swift cannot make a print of it, and in this case it would be 2 ways, first xcode would ask to define description for my custom struct, or xcode would force to print anything that it can print from my custom struct, which is not what i am looking, I want `Any` type which they conform 100% to `CustomStringConvertible `

Comment: This is why I said `Any` *might* be better.  Your restricting to `CustomStringConvertible` is a case where `Any` is not the better choice.

Comment: Basically the issue is here that, I should use generic which that should be `CustomStringConvertible` or using Value type that would be `Any`, if i use `Any` then how can I conform to a protocol like `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: No need to use a closure here `map(String.init(describing:))`

Answer (score 1):

When you are defining generic type T, you're actually giving the specific type for parameters that you will pass. If you give String parameter first, the function expects all the parameter types as String. If you give Int parameter first, function expects all parameters as Int. You should not use generic in this function. [NoeOnJupiter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73178495/12577044) can be usable in your case.